# Make Phone Connected to Modem Ring

Tags: c#, .net, modem, phone-call

I have an old landline phone and am looking for a way to make it ring when it's connected to the modem of my home server. I want to use it as a notification when a build is broken and stuff like that. Like most modems, the one in my server has two line jacks, one for data and one for a phone. Since I can only programmatically manipulate the data line, I'm guessing I'm going to have to plug the phone into the data line and simulate a connection somehow but that's where I'm drawing a blank.

I've read up on phone phreaking and telephone ringing circuits but I'm not real sure how that would translate to code, if at all. I can't imagine I'm the only one to think about this so I'm guessing it's either not possible or too hard to be practical. Any help is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once put my multimeter across the phone line and then made it ring. This was probably 20+ years ago, but I still remember: the line went up to 90+ volts (AC). So I guess the phone expects to see a 90v signal for it to ring. It seems highly unlikely that the modem would be able to emit that signal, and also unlikely that the modem could provide the necessary current (as Martin said).

I have one idea but it will depend on your phone line provider. I don't know if it still works, but years ago in Australia you could dial a certain short number and then hang up, and the exchange would call you back right away. Very useful for the phone tech to test the line I guess. So if you can find out if your provider has a number that does that, all you have to do is command the modem to dial that number and then hang up. Then you can keep monitoring the line and after it rings a few times, tell the modem to pick up and hang up again to make it stop ringing.

Here's an idea that doesn't use the modem at all. You could connect to a VOIP service (there must be APIs for some of them) and just dial your phone number through that. You'd never answer so it would never cost anything.

Answer (score 4):

Generating ringing power is beyond the capabilities of modems.  The only way you could ring the phone is to actually have two real switch lines, connect the phone to one, modem to the other and actually call the phone.

Answer (score 3):

Someone asked similar question in 2004 and get answered in 2010. for your reference: http://www.overclockers.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-283831.html

Comment: For convenience, [here's a direct link to the answer](http://www.sm0vpo.com/_visitors/inst/ring-gen.htm).  (Port 80 seems to work just as well as port 800.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use a land line phone?
If the server is connected to the internet you could ring your mobile (or send an sms message) whenever a build fails.

Otherwise you could hook up speakers to the server and play a ring tone through the speakers whenever you need to.